# How would one design a circuit to detect energy in the 3-140GHz ranges economically

Tags: rf, analog, filter, band-pass

We are looking to make something to detect RF frequencies in the SHF and EHF bands, from 3-140GHz, without requiring much frequency or amplitude accuracy.  It would be ideally split into a few bands, e.g. 3-30GHz, 30-60GHz, 60-100GHz, and 100-140GHz.  So essentially any energy in each of those bands above some threshold would just trigger a logical output.  Being able to quantify the intensity of the energy would be a bonus (and again it doesn't need spectrum analyzer precision), but not essential.

So it seems to me that I won't be able to design any simple active bandpass filters in those frequency ranges, although I suppose I can develop passive bandpass filters with the right components.  But I haven't found components yet that appear to support those bands.  I'm also not sure how to deal with antenna requirements.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: Read up on crystal detectors.

Comment: How sensitive i.e. what sort of antenna level signal amplitudes?

Comment: How economical do you need this to be, ie. roughly what is your budget?  Most devices in the upper range of your design description are very expensive...

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Interesting about crystal detectors - are there any commercialized products for this?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not too sure how to specify this, but we would like to detect power in the range of 10W/m^2  The device should be fairly small though, so maybe 25mW.

Comment: @DakotaD Hopefully something in the hundreds to low thousands of dollars.  I would work with lower bands first if the 60GHz+ bands are not feasible.

Comment: @AngeloQ I don't think you'll be able to do the upper bands for the price you desire unless you're able to spread the cost among multiple devices.  For example, commercial W-band diode detectors run around $3-4k/piece, see Fairview Microwave.  You could design your own diode based detector, see Virginia Diodes, but they have a $2000 minimum order amount.  You may be able to design a cheap bolometer style device using waveguide below cutoff for low-pass filtering, high-pass would be another issue.